# How to Divide A list in to 3 columns

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

[CodePen Project](https://codepen.io/TheAnB/pen/mazgLO)

If you visit the page you can see that the list(ul) is simply listed vertically

I want to list season 1,2,3 completely seperately in three columns (like down below)

```
S01E01   S02E01  S01E01
S01E02   S02E02  S01E02
S01E03   S02E03  S01E03
```

And the other problem is the width for the list, in the the site some of the items of the list is partially in the next line.

```
    S01 E03 · The Would-Be Prince of
Darkness
```

like this(like in the web)

it gets affected by the width

```
.tv  {
list-style: none;
width: 300px;
border-radius: 2px;
}
```

when I set width higher long lines are complete but few short items are displayed in the same line

I need to fix those two problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 60%;
```

Comment: added it to the list(tv) but it doesn't work it makes an item display in few lines

Comment: Set this style to your div you want to have as a three-colums list. Something like .tv  {
display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 60%;}

Comment: it succesfull seperated it into 3 columns but what i typed is too long so one item is about 4 lines

Comment: add  {  overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; }   to the column with the long text

Comment: Like THIS?
`div
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}`

Comment: <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="boxA">A</div>
  <div class="boxB">B</div>
  <div class="boxC">CCCCC</div>
</div>
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 10% 80%;
}
.boxC {
overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;}

Answer (score 0):

Dude Try putting every 'ul' including every season in a div and the give div this property

```
div{
        float:left;
        width: 30%;
    }
```

OR maybe look at this test code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    html, body{
        font-family: "Verdana";
    }
    div{
        float:left;
        width: 30%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><h1>HELLO</h1></div>
<div><h1>HELLO</h1></div>
<div><h1>HELLO</h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it succesfull seperated it into 3 columns but what i typed is too long so one item is about 4 lines [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/TheAnB/pen/mazgLO)